# How do I add a start menu entry for a text file in CPACK ans NSIS

Tags: cmake, nsis, cpack

I want an entry for `release_notes.txt` or `release_notes.html` in the start-menu. When I select the release_notes entry in the menu the text file shall apear in notepad or the html fill in a web browser. But I can't figure out how to write the commands in `CMakeLists.txt` to do that.

Comment: Dating back to at least Win2000 the MS guidelines tell you to not create startmenu entries for help/uninstaller/etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `CPACK_NSIS_MENU_LINKS`?

Or you could use [`CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_INSTALL_COMMANDS`](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/CPACK-on-windows-td5796081.html)...

Comment: CPACK_NSIS_MENU_LINKS solved the problem. I also found that it is documented in CPackNSIS.cmake.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if current versions of CMake provide an easier/different way, but this is what we do:

```
SET( CPACK_NSIS_CREATE_ICONS_EXTRA 
"
CreateShortcut \\\"$SMPROGRAMS\\\\$STARTMENU_FOLDER\\\\SDK Documentation.lnk\\\" \\\"$INSTDIR\\\\doc\\\\html\\\\index.html\\\"
" )

SET( CPACK_NSIS_DELETE_ICONS_EXTRA 
"
Delete \\\"$SMPROGRAMS\\\\$MUI_TEMP\\\\SDK Documentation.lnk\\\"
" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Johannes' answer, *CPACK_NSIS_CREATE_ICONS_EXTRA* and *CPACK_NSIS_DELETE_ICONS_EXTRA* is a flexible way to manage shortcuts (Start menu, desktop, etc.), including adding command-line arguments if required. [This short article](http://crascit.com/2015/08/07/cmake_cpack_nsis_shortcuts_with_parameters/) gives a bit more information. It uses a slightly different path for the delete link with an explanation for why. It also includes links to NSIS documentation to show other places you can create shortcuts, etc.